# Regex: Match everything after first blank line

Tags: c#, regex

I am trying to create a regex that matches everything after but not including the first blank line in c#.

Example:

having input of:

```
This is header info
that I dont'  : really want
in my file

I want everything below this line
until the end of the file

even this stuff
```

would result in:

```
I want everything below this line
until the end of the file

even this stuff
```

Comment: You'll probably get a better answer if you tell us what language/program you're going to use this regex with.

Comment: You need to show some context. What do you mean by "input", is it a file you are reading, is it all stored in one string, are you reading a file one line at a time, etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use single line and multiline flag in a regex like this:

```
^$.*
```

**[Working demo](https://regex101.com/r/zT8kI5/1)**

[image]

Btw, if you have multiple white spaces in the line, then you could use:

```
^\s*$(.*)
```

And then grab the content from the capturing group